# Gutenberg MediaUpload component with default gallery functionality?

Tags: gallery, block-editor

I have seen a few tutorials around utilizing the MediaUpload component from below.

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/editor/src/components/media-upload

But none of them demonstrate it with the default gallery functionality that is common pre-Gutenberg. For example the ability to select multiple images and then be taken to a second screen where you can order and caption them. See attachments if further info is needed.

There is the **multiple** attribute which can be set to "true" or "add" but it doesn't toggle the second screen for ordering the items or captioning them.

[image: 1st Screen]

[image: 2nd Screen]

Comment: MediaUpload component documentation is here :
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/HEAD/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-upload/README.md As said before you must set gallery and multiple props to true.
The value props must be an array of media ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't documented but if we take a look to the [gallery block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/gallery/edit.js#L200), we see it passes an extra prop to the MediaUpload component.

Try to pass `gallery` as well as `multiple` to the component.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I appreciate the prompt response! Is there any documentation for it besides the source? I'm getting unexpected results, e.g. passing in an empty array for values and all images are selected by default :/

Comment: @DevonMather Glad it helped. I don't know, I always check the github repository (as the [handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/) takes the content from there, if I'm correct). There I can check the actual code of the component in the same place. Maybe you can open another question or extend this one?